# Bootstrap-affix pausing scrollwheel functionality in chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-affix

I am trying to implement a bootstrap affixed navbar. Everything seemed to be functioning as expected, however a strange issue is occurring in google chrome. When you scroll by the navbar in such a way that one of the mousewheel events fires on the navbar as it affixes, the scrollwheel completely stops functioning until some other mouse input such as a movement or a click occurs.

This can be easily reproduced by just directly copying the w3schools affix example into an html document and opening it in chrome. If you place the mouse at the top of the screen and attempt to scroll down, it will catch. Any mouse movement restores scrolling but it makes navigating the page far clunkier. Ive copied the exact code below (unedited from w3schools).

The issue does not appear to occur in either firefox, edge, or IE. The issue also does not occur on the actual w3schools website, or testing services. I believe this is due to some of the interaction from wrapping the code in an iframe

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Note: Try to remove the following lines to see the effect of CSS positioning */
  .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
  <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
  <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
  <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
  <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" style="height:2000px">
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```